# Подключение к smb шаре с активным параметром EncryptData

Tags: java, smb

Имею java, windows smb шару и библиотеку jcifs-ng.
При попытке подключиться к шаре со значением параметра `EncryptData: True` (параметр выставлен в свойствах шары), получаю ошибку `jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Access is denied`. При `EncryptData: False` подключение проходит успешно.

Как успешно подключиться при `EncryptData: True`? Почему не получается?

Comment: А никакие дополнительные параметры относящиеся к шифрованию не нужно устанавливать/указывать?

Comment: @XelaNimed Вот в поиске. Пробую разные из jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration, но положительного результата нет.